# LOADING message of phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When I try to create a database using phpmyadmin, and XAMPP panel control  it gives the following loading message which never ends!!  any ideas??

```
Chargement en cours / Loading in process
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved! i uninstalled XAMPP and reinstalled it!